# Issue integrating Selenium test suite using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-rc

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with Selenium. I have prepared the following command:

```
java -jar "D:\CI\TWCP\Selenium plugins\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar" -htmlSuite *firefox "http://www.google.co.in"  "C:\Users\....\Desktop\Test suites\GoogleTestSuite.html" "C:\Users\.....\Desktop\results.html" -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\....\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\s980v5zn.default"
```

When I execute the command in the command line, it works Perfectly fine. Then I called the same command through Jenkins and I got the following error:

```
    Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace D:\CI\Jenkins\jobs\Google Test\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson600399625489206831.bat

D:\CI\Jenkins\jobs\Google Test\workspace>java -jar "D:\CI\TWCP\Selenium plugins\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar" -htmlSuite *firefox "http://www.google.co.in"  "C:\Users\N_chandanKumar\Desktop\Test suites\GoogleTestSuite.html" "C:\Users\N_chandanKumar\Desktop\results.html" -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\Users\N_chandanKumar\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\s980v5zn.default" 
Apr 24, 2013 10:54:07 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
10:54:08.647 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 1.6.0-b105
10:54:08.647 INFO - OS: Windows Vista 6.1 x86
10:54:08.662 INFO - v2.32.0, with Core v2.32.0. Built from revision 6c40c18
10:54:08.756 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
10:54:08.756 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
10:54:08.756 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
10:54:08.756 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
10:54:08.756 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
10:54:08.787 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@13c1b02
10:54:08.787 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
10:54:08.787 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
10:54:08.787 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@7ced01
jar:file:/D:/CI/TWCP/Selenium%20plugins/selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar!/customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME
10:54:09.941 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
10:54:12.041 INFO - Launching Firefox...
10:54:14.242 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
10:54:37.079 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
10:54:37.079 INFO - Received posted results
GoogleTestCase.html
<a href="GoogleTestCase.html">GoogleTestCase</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>


10:54:37.297 INFO - Killing Firefox...
Tests failed, see result file for details: C:\Users\N_chandanKumar\Desktop\results.html
10:54:37.921 INFO - Shutting down...
10:54:37.921 INFO - Stopping Acceptor ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=4444]

D:\CI\Jenkins\jobs\Google Test\workspace>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

result.html shows failure with below log

```
info: Starting test /selenium-server/tests/GoogleTestCase.html
info: Executing: |setTimeout | 1000000 |  |
info: Executing: |openAndWait | http://www.google.co.in/ |  |
info: Executing: |setTimeout | 1000000 |  |
info: Executing: |pause | 20000 |  |
info: Executing: |verifyTextPresent | India |  |
warn: currentTest.recordFailure: false
info: Executing: |assertTitle | Google |  |
error: Actual value &apos;Error Message&apos; did not match &apos;Google&apos;
warn: currentTest.recordFailure: Actual value &apos;Error Message&apos; did not match &apos;Google&apos;
```

If I run the same code adding **debug** tag i.e.

```
java -jar "D:\CI\TWCP\Selenium plugins\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar" -htmlSuite *firefox "http://www.google.co.in"  "C:\Users\....\Desktop\Test suites\GoogleTestSuite.html" "C:\Users\....\Desktop\results.html" -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\Users\.....\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\s980v5zn.default" -debug
```

I get the following logs at the end

```
GoogleTestCase.html
<a href="GoogleTestCase.html">GoogleTestCase</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>



10:58:56.737 DEBUG - Handled by org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SeleniumHTMLRunnerResultsHandler@14b7453
10:58:56.737 DEBUG - RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 05:28:56 GMT
Server: Jetty/5.1.x (Windows Vista/6.1 x86 java/1.6.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


10:58:57.002 INFO - Killing Firefox...
10:58:57.018 DEBUG - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
10:58:57.018 DEBUG - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
10:58:57.018 DEBUG - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
10:58:57.018 DEBUG - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
10:58:57.033 DEBUG - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
10:58:57.033 DEBUG - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Tests failed, see result file for details: C:\Users\N_chandanKumar\Desktop\results.html
D:\CI\Jenkins\jobs\Google Test\workspace>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have jenkins 1.509 and seleniumHQ2.32.0

Not able to make out how I am getting **"java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"** Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
cK

Comment: Some things to keep in mind while configuring UI tests are:  1) The slave should be connected to server preferably by Java Web Start and not let Jenkins control this Windows slave as a Windows service. 2) Use `start java -jar ...` instead of directly giving `java -jar ..` in the batch command. This will let the selenium server to be started in a new command window.

Comment: Shiva, Thanks for your suggestions. But sorry to say it didn't help. It didn't even run properly . 

D:\CI\Jenkins\jobs\Google Test\workspace>start java -jar "D:\CI\TWCP\Selenium plugins\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar" -htmlSuite *firefox "http://www.google.co.in"  "C:\Users\N_chandanKumar\Desktop\Test suites\GoogleTestSuite.html" "C:\Users\N_chandanKumar\Desktop\results.html" -firefoxProfileTemplate "D:\twcpUserProfile" -debug 

D:\CI\Jenkins\jobs\Google Test\workspace>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Sorry it did not help. Just to crosscheck, is there a semicolon really after google.co.in or was it just garbled here?

Comment: No, there is no semicolon , it is just garbled

Answer (score 1):

To check on the issue I ran the jenkins server in Interactive mode. The setting can be seen when you go to services.msc -> Jenkins process -> properties-> click on logon tab and you can select Local system account and tick "Allow service to interact with desktop".

This made jenkins to run the selenium test interactively instead of running in background.

There I could observe browser failing to open the website. This was tackled by following settings services.msc -> Jenkins process -> properties-> click on logon tab --> Select this account and give the account using which you have logged into this system.